# How do I find organization repositories by organization id in Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

I will get organization id as the input and I need to list all the repositories by that organization sorted by the number of stars. I tried looking at Github documentation and couldn't find anything useful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier when you give the organization key (like dlang etc.) for input.
Then you could list the repository with the the search api:
GET https://api.github.com/search?q=org:{your org}&sort=stars&order=desc